# Поиск #tag NSString or UITextView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Такая ситуевина, есть поле для обзывание обьекта, в котором можно обзывать объект тегами. Желательно это делать сразу в методе

> - (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView;

Мне нужно просто найти слово, которое начинается на @"#" и заканчивается @" " и сделать его синим цветом и кастомным шрифтом, но все мои попытки потерпели фиаско.

Может кто-то сталкивался с этим и имеет идеи по реализации ?

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Tags) изучите код, и юзайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Таким образом можно получить тэги:

```
 NSArray *words = [textView.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
 NSArray *tags = [words filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH %@", @"#"]];
```

а насчет подсветки может помочь: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/coretexthyperlinkview